# I tried a new way to create routes on express and this happened, any suggestions?

Tags: node.js, express, server

I created a basic express server and defined an empty variable. Then! I created a function named switchURL with 2 parameters (REQ, RES). Then I invoked that function and passed express.request and express.response as parameter values. Inside function I created a switch statement and set the key to REQ.url and added some cases for routes that I want to get on my server. and set the file names to path variable (empty variable). What happened next you can see.

```js
function switchURL(REQ, RES) {
  switch (REQ.url) {
    case "/":
      path = "index.html"
      break
    case "/about":
      path = "about.html"
      break
    case "/contact":
      path = "contact.html"
      break
    default:
      path = "404.html"
      break
  }
  console.log(REQ.url)
  console.log(path)
  app.get(REQ.url, () => {
    RES.sendFile(__dirname + "public/pages/" + path)
  })
}
switchURL(express.request, express.response)
```

Wrote a function and expected that It will read req.url property and send the html file as response

Comment: Reference [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to see how to use static files properly.